# How to create mysql master slave replication from backup?

Tags: mysql, replication

I am using sqlbak to back up my database. Here are the backup files look like:
[image]

Here is the content:

[image]

[image]

Typically, there should be one bin log file and one location to restore and be a slave. We back up the database for different schema(since the database is too big), and each sql file indicates a different bin log file and location.

Is this possible to restore the database to another server and be a slave?
Or do we need to back up the database to a single SQL file for the master-slave replication?

Comment: fyi - [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would make one backup file, because that allows you to start replication from a single binary log coordinate.

You could get away with making multiple dump files only if there are no writes occurring on all but one of the schemas. So you would back up and restore all of the quiescent schemas, then finally back up and restore the one schema that has writes, and use the binary log coordinate of that backup.

For what it's worth, at my last job we used Percona XtraBackup to make the full backups much more quickly. This is a physical backup, not an SQL dump type of backup, so it restores instantly. The disadvantage is that the replica MySQL instance must be shut down as you restore, and the restore overwrites whatever was on the replica before.